# Shrinkwrap tetris shapes without scaling or diagonal shapes

Tags: animation, mesh, shrinkwrap

Hello guys I want to achieve a Shrinkwrap modifier from a sphere to a tetris shape like this. This shape was achieved by merging two cubes Scale (1,2,1) and (1,1,1) I also tried getting this shape by modifying the vertices but the results of the shrinkwrap were the same

[image]

I kind of already did other shrinkwrap shapes that worked perfectly like these

[image]

These are exactly the way I want the shrinkwraps to work by adding a shrinkwrap modifier and putting the mode to nearest vertex and setting the target as the shape I wanted but all of these were made with cubes in where only the scale got changed. The mode nearest surface point needed me to scale the sphere so it fits the shape but I cant scale the sphere (the game I develop doesnt allow it) so the mode nearest vertex did the thing I exactly wanted. This is what I got when I try to shrinkwrap the tetris shape

[image]

the shape doesnt select all the vertices as a whole shape like the ones before so the outcome will not be good. Somehow there are even triangle shapes outside the actual shape.

So how do I achieve the shrinkwrap to perfectly wrap around my tetris shape (just realized its not even a tetris shape) without triangles and that.

I'd be grateful for any tips (I am a newbie in blender btw)

Answer (score 5):

Avoid Boolean whenever possible. For such simple shapes you should not need any "merging" , [proper topology is important](https://topologyguides.com/) especially if you are deforming shapes where constant mesh density is helpful.

If you just want the morph into a sphere use the *Cast* modifier instead, it yields cleaner results.

Model the shape by extruding two faces of a default cube, then add a *Subsurf* modifier set to *Simple* to give it geometry to work with, followed by the *Cast* modifier set to *Sphere*. Control progression from the *Factor* slider.

[image: Morph]

Comment: I want to morph from sphere to the tetris shape and also without having a massive big ball

Comment: You can adjust radius and morphing order from the modifier